# Wayland not working in 21.10 with Nvidia driver v495

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, wayland, 21.10

I have a Lenovo Gaming 3i 15IMH05 with an i7 10750H and a GTX 1650 with Windows 10, Ubuntu 21.10 and macOS 11.4 installed. I also have GNOME installed besides the default Ubuntu session, with both of them defaulting to X11.

If I choose "Ubuntu on Wayland" from the login screen, it throws me into a black screen with no mouse and never loads the DE. Clicking the power button does suspend the system, and then I can boot it up again to login normally on an X11 session.

Choosing "GNOME on Wayland" flashes the screen briefly before throwing me back at the login screen every time.

I remember in the first time I booted on 21.10 it was using a Wayland session normally, but I spent a month w/o going back to Ubuntu because having my second monitor connected crashed Ubuntu on boot up with the v480 drivers (similar problems happen in Windows, seems like a bug with my hardware and Nvidia drivers). But now Wayland just doesn't want to work.

Is there a solution to this?

My Nvidia driver install:
[image: Screenshot of Software & Updates screen from Ubuntu, showing "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-495" selected]

Comment: Considering that something is affecting both Windows and Ubuntu then before anything else you should update UEFI. Also please don't mention MacOS because that is an "hack" that violates its ToS and is off-topic here and anywhere else in the StackExchange network.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I could do that and probably will, but I don't see how UEFI is connected to it.

Comment: UEFI, like the old BIOS before, is the motherboard's firmware responsible among many other tasks for the correct hardware initialization. That alone can affect everything. Even brand new systems often need firmware updates especially for Linux.

Comment: **Nvidia currently doesn't work with Wayland**. Go back to your login screen and reset it to use X11/xorg.

Comment: While this is a [discussion within Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/WaylandByDefaultOnNVIDIA#Current_status), the details suggest that the proprietary NVIDIA drivers now support Wayland via the DRM KMS @heynnema. The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wayland#Requirements) also suggests that NVIDIA is supported via the EGLStreams API.